# Creating game with different game modes and settings, how to handle all the different settings?

Tags: java, android, settings

I am creating a game in which you can either play against computers or humans with multiple (advanced) settings for each, the variety of possible games get large quickly when adding new settings.

I want to write clean code and **I face the problem that I need to write a lot of "unnecessary" checks for all possible optional/mutual exclusive options**. Unnecessary because when the game was created with specific settings it could already know its options and thus which checks are redundant. I see little reasons for continuously checking for e.g. if the game has only computers, humans or a mix of both.

I know of the **Builder-pattern** which can solve the problem of having many parameters to pass into a constructor of which many are optional. I can use this when I create a game. This solves the problem of having a hard time constructing the game. However this still requires a lot of checks during the time the game is run to see which settings are set and which not.

Any leads for me to look into?

---

### Code Example (Only illustration)

```
    Mode mode;
    Vocabulary mVocabulary;
    Player[] mPlayers;
    GameLog mGameLog;
    String mCurrentString;
    int mMinimalWordLength = 3;
    int mIndexActivePlayer;
    int mNumberOfActivePlayers;
    boolean mComputers; //[Optional]
    int mNumberOfComputers; //[Required if mComputer is true]
    Difficulty mDifficulty; //[Required if mComputer is true]

    //One of these optionals are required
    boolean mBlueTooth; //[Optional]
    boolean online; //[Optional]
    boolean sameDevice; //[Optional]

    //Here I could use the builder pattern to set all the options
    public Game(Vocabulary vocabulary, int numberOfPlayers, int minimalWordLength, Player[] players) {
        this.mVocabulary = vocabulary;
        this.mMinimalWordLength = minimalWordLength;
        this.numberOfActivePlayers = numberOfPlayers;
        this.mPlayers = players;
    }
}
```

I am creating a game which requires a `mVocabulary` of words, with a list of players `mPlayers` and a couple of optional settings. Each game is either created for computers or humans or a mix of both. Each game either is `online`, via `blue-toot` or on the `sameDevice`.

Based on these options different things happen throughout the code, so you could write a couple of if else if statements in each method that follows this code. However I want to prevent this.

**If you see your program as a decision tree in which you are at a particular time at a specific point in your program, then you know that once a game is created in a specific way where you should look and where not to look.** Since you're in a specific branch of the tree. For example, you create a game with only humans, a weird thing to do would to keep checking each turn if a player is human if you know that there are only human player, since that is the way you created the game in the first place.

I hope this make my point more clear. Although not a full code example is written.

Comment: This is a very very abstract requirement. If you provide some examples supporting each of your statements, it would be really helpful to provide an answer closest to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it's the best approach, but I avoid too many checks by subclassing and implementing 'hook' methods (an idea I borrowed from `Rails` hooks, actually).

For instance, imagine you have a `ParentGame` class and `BlueToothGame`, `OnlineGame` and `SameDeviceGame` children. You'd implement all common logic in `ParentGame`, such as.-

```
public void mainLoop() {
    startOfMainLoop();
    // Some stuff
    checkWinLoseCondition();
}
```

Where `startOfMainLoop` and `checkWinLoseCondition()` could be abstract methods to be implemented on children classes. This way, you encapsulate common logic, and implement specific behavior for each 'kind/configuration of game', without messing your code with lots of checks along your main game logic.

Just an idea, though, of course the best approach depends on your current scenario :)